# Earning Yearling badge does it get me 200 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, yearling-badge

I earned recently the Yearling badge, as the message says in the achievements : (active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation), am i supposed to get 200 reputation? because i did not receive anything

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.
Having 200 reputation is one of the requirements to get that badge.

Comment: To elaborate on that, *"active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation"* simply means that earning 200 reputation during the year is how the system considers that you've been *"active"*. If you've earned 200 rep then you get the badge, not the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

You earned this badge because you have 200+ reputation and you have an active account for 1 year +. This badge won't give you any reputation.

Few details about this badge <sup><sub>[link to the source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/314988)</sub></sup> :--

#### Yearling

- silver; awarded multiple times
- Have a reputation of at least (number of years since registration) × 200 + 1 (starting reputation)

  - The number of years is not restricted to integers and increases continuously. For example, if at the 2-year mark you don’t have the 400 required reputation, the number of years still continues to increase. So half way through year 3 (i.e., after 2.5 years), you’d need 2.5 × 200 = 500 reputation to qualify for the second yearling badge.
  - If at any point you qualify for this year’s badge, you will receive all badges you had previously missed up until this year whenever the script runs again.
  - The badge used to require only (years) × 100 reputation; this was [changed after the account association bonus was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32626)